# Will the command line arguments be "passed twice"?

Tags: c, linux, x86

I am trying to understand how command line arguments work in details.

This is what I think happens:

- When you compile a source code that contains the `main()` function in C, the generated object file will be linked with the CRT, and the entry point for the program will be the `_start()` function (which exists in the CRT), and `_start()` will call `main()`.
- Now when you run your program and pass it some command line arguments, the command line arguments will be passed to the `_start()` function, and then `_start()` will re-pass the command line arguments to `main()`.

Am I correct?

Comment: "… the entry point for the program will be the " `main` function. Anything else is irrelevant for your C program. If you want to go deeper, this is not related to C, but solely to your platform. Using Linux, reading the source code of the crt and the loader and single-stepping a simple program. It is definitively far too broad to explain all this here.

Comment: The pointer representing the array of arguments, and the argument count, are passed around. The arguments themselves got processed by the runtime.

Comment: The shell interpreting the command line will parse the parameters and will populate the array of arguments.  It then passes the count and pointer to main through a compiler specific method (either puts them on the stack, or more likely populates registers with these values prior to invoking main).

Answer (score 4):

> Am I correct?

Yes and no:

The `_start()` function is not a C function but an assembler function. The reason for this is that the CPU is not in a "state" which is required by C programs so the `_start()` function also has to set up the CPU for executing C code.

One difference between the "state" required by C programs and the "state" of the CPU when `_start()` is called is the way arguments (here: command line arguments) are stored.

Under Linux (at least 32 bit - I don't know about 64 bit) you actually have an array that later represents `argv`. `_start()` has to calculate the location of `argv` and then pass the calculated value to `main()`.

Under Windows there is a function that returns the entire command line as pointer to a single string (`const char *`)! The `_start()` function has to call that function and then to split the string into parts that will later become `argv`...

Comment: x86-64 Linux is basically the same as i386 as far as stack layout on process entry.  argc and pointers are 64 bits wide, though.  The ABIs document the details.  https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI